# Query Lag – Single Row Select Takes Over 2 Minutes to Complete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Query Lag – Single Row Select Takes Over 2 Minutes to Complete

SQL Server 10.50.4000.0 (2008 R2 SP2)

Step 1 – Populate the Test Table

```
begin tran
truncate table MSDS_PROD_BK..MSDS_Import
insert into    MSDS_PROD_BK..MSDS_Import
select * from  MSDS_PROD..MSDS_Import (nolock)
commit tran
```

(30354 row(s) affected)

(takes 32 seconds to complete)

(IMPORTANT NOTE – the table contains a VARBINARY column)

Step 2 – Select the VARBINARY column for just 1 row (via new query window, database: MSDS_PROD_BK)

```
SELECT distinct FILE_DATA 
FROM MSDS_Import 
WHERE FILE_NAME = ‘example.pdf’
```

(takes 2 minutes to complete)

(IMPORTANT NOTE – while this is running, the very same query returns sub-second [response time] from other new and existing sessions and yes, if DISTINCT was not specified, you don’t get the lag)

(subsequently, all such queries now returning sub-second [response time])

During the Lag Time, running sp_who2 shows no blocking but sp_lock shows:

```
dbid    ObjId   IndId   Type    Resource    Mode    Status
75  0   0   MD  2(35e8b1ea:b:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:a:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  2(35e8b1ea:a:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:b:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  2(35e8b1ea:9:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:8:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  2(35e8b1ea:8:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:9:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  2(35e8b1ea:3:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:3:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  2(35e8b1ea:1:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:1:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:1:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  2(35e8b1ea:7:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:6:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  2(35e8b1ea:6:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:7:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  2(35e8b1ea:5:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:4:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  2(35e8b1ea:4:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
75  0   0   MD  1(35e8b1ea:5:0)                     Sch-S   GRANT
```

Question – What’s going on behind-the-scene for this first-hit-look at the VARBINARY column?

Of course, planning to try installing SP3

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you have no indexes whatsoever.

Comment: Sounds like the `DISTINCT` is being applied before the `WHERE`; so it's reading all 30,354 VARBINARY fields?  Could you supply the actual execution plan?  *(Although this is what it feels like to me, I'm confident/hoping that I must be wrong.)*

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is the culprit. It means that no duplicates shall be delivered, but in order to find duplicates, the engine needs to read and compare the content of all the binary fields.

Comment: i agree that the DISTINCT is the culprit - yet, while the query is spinning its wheels running for over two minutes, i can open a new query window, run the same identical query and it completes sub-second (while the 1st hit query is still running and running

Comment: the table has a primary key and the estimated query plan says it's doing a clustered index scan (even though query columns FILE_DATA and FILE_NAME are not part of the index - odd?)

Answer (score 0):

```html
with ctefiledate
as
(
 SELECT FILE_DATA 
 FROM MSDS_Import 
 WHERE FILE_NAME = 'example.pdf'
)
select distinct file_data from ctefiledate
```

---

check with above code

Thanks